# Sitecore Could not create controller : Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ControllerCreationException

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I am using Sitecore v9

I have a two base class for all my controllers as follows

```
public abstract SiteCoreController : ControllerBase, IController, IActionFilter, IAuthenticationFilter, IAuthorizationFilter, IDisposable, IExceptionFilter, IResultFilter, IAsyncController, IAsyncManagerContainer

public abstract class ControllerBase : IController
```

All controllers use something like

```
public class MyPageController : SiteCoreController
```

In my log files I get heaps of errors

> Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ControllerCreationException: Could not create
> controller:  The context item is: '/sitecore/content/TEST/home'. The
> current route url is: '{*pathInfo}'. This is the default Sitecore
> route which is set up in the 'InitializeRoutes' processor of the
> 'initialize' pipeline. ---> Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ExceptionWrapper:
> The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement
> IController. at
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
> requestContext, Type controllerType) at
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
> requestContext, String controllerName) at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
> requestContext, String controllerName)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
> requestContext, String controllerName) at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.GetController() at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute() at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Request.RequestBegin.ExecuteFormHandler.ExecuteHandler(String
> controllerName, String actionName, RequestBeginArgs args) at (Object ,
> Object[] ) at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
> pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String
> pipelineName, TArgs args) at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
> context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
> completedSynchronously)

My DI is setup as follows

```
public static void SetupControllers(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, params Assembly[] assemblyArray)
{
    var controllers = GetTypesImplementing<IController>(assemblyArray)
        .Where(controller => controller.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.Ordinal));

    foreach (var x in controllers)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(x);
    }

    var apis = GetTypesImplementing<ApiController>(assemblyArray)
        .Where(controller => controller.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.Ordinal));

    foreach (var x in apis)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the controller causing the problem. Does it have dependencies? Have they all been registered correctly? Most times this happens because the controller factory was unable to resolve all the necessary dependencies to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have forgotten to register the controller in [Sitecore DI container](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/dependency-injection.html).

Here is [an example (Option 1: Just use Sitecore’s Container)](https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2016/09/17/Habitat-Dependency-Injection-with-Sitecore-8-2/).

In our project we've created a dummy `ControllerAttribute` attribute to put on controllers we need to be automatically created.

Next - own Configurator that registers types from the namespace to DI, like:

```
var enumerable = from type in assemblies.Where((Assembly assembly) => !assembly.IsDynamic).SelectMany(GetExportedTypes)
    where !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    select new
    {
        Lifetime = type.GetCustomAttribute<ControllerAttribute>()?.Lifetime,
        ServiceType = type,
        ImplementationType = type.GetCustomAttribute<ControllerAttribute>()?.ControllerType
    } into t
    where t.Lifetime.HasValue
    select t;
foreach (var item in enumerable)
{
    if (item.ImplementationType == null)
    {
        serviceCollection.Add(item.ServiceType, item.Lifetime.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        serviceCollection.Add(item.ImplementationType, item.ServiceType, item.Lifetime.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my original question with the DI setup, is there an issue there?

Comment: @MicroMan Could you check running DI config via `sitecore/admin/showservicesConfig.aspx` to ensure controller got registered.

Comment: There are ton of Services registered in there, i am not sure which on is causing the issue, i just see lots of errors in my logger which doesn't specify which controller?

Comment: @MicroMan I assume you've created a Sitecore item + assigned the controller rendering on it, correct? The controller rendering definition item defines controller type to use.
You can verify the type to be created is shown in showServices, as well as all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's relevant for anyone but I'll post how I fixed it:

**Background**

1. Sitecore 9.2 using GlassMapper & Microsoft DI.
2. Helix solution pattern.

**Problem**

All my controllers were loading except 2. After grinding my head for few hours noticed there were spelling mistakes in those 2 controllers.

**Solution**

Changed controller *mis-spelled* name `PersonalizationContoller` to `PersonalizationController`

As I understand due to the 'r' missing in the controller name, the DI was not considering it as a controller thus not registered. Simply go to `/sitecore/admin/showservicesConfig.aspx` & check if your controller is registered - if not then either the name is wrong or the controller is using dependencies not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if by chance you missed to make the class as public.

```
class MyPageController : Controller{
}
```

It should be

```
public class MyPageController : Controller{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **misspelling** issue! Check Controller name it should match the name in the `Layout/renderings/` or `Layout/Sublayout` **controller field** value.

[image]